# Proving Taylor series remainder formula

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

Suppose $f$ is an infinite times differentiable function whose Taylor series converges. I'm trying to prove $$\lim_{w \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{r=0}^{w - 1} \frac{f^{n+1+r}(a)}{(n+1+r)!}(x-a)^{n+1+r}=\frac{1}{n!}\int_a^x (x-t)^{n}f^{n+1}(t)dt$$

(where $f^{n+1}$ is nth derivative of $f$)

by this method:

$$RHS=\frac{1}{n!}\int_a^x (x-t)^{n}f^{n+1}(t)dt=\lim_{w \rightarrow \infty} \frac{h}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{w-1} ((x-a)-kh))^nf^{n+1}(a+kh)$$

(where $h=\frac{x-a}{w}$)

$$=\lim_{w \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x-a}{wn!} \sum_{k=0}^{w-1} \left(\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r (x-a)^{n-r} \left(k\frac{x-a}{w}\right)^r\right)f^{n+1}(a+kh)\right)$$

$$=\lim_{w\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{w-1} \left(\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \frac{k^r}{w^{r+1}}\right)f^{n+1}(a+kh)\right)$$

So, this is an expansion of $\frac{1}{n!}\int_a^x (x-t)^{n}f^{n+1}(t)dt$ with terms of the form $c_kf^{n+1}(a+kh)$ with coefficients $c_k$ being $\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{n!}\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \frac{k^r}{w^{r+1}}$

Now,

$$LHS=\lim_{w \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{r=0}^{w - 1} \frac{f^{n+1+r}(a)}{(n+1+r)!}(x-a)^{n+1+r}$$

Using $$f^{n+1+r}(a)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{r}{k} (-1)^{r-k} f^{n+1} (a+kh)}{h^r}$$

$$=\lim_{w\rightarrow \infty} \frac{w^r \sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{r}{k} (-1)^{r-k} f^{n+1} (a+kh)}{(x-a)^r}$$

$$LHS=\lim_{w \rightarrow \infty}\left( \sum_{r=0}^{w - 1} \frac{(x-a)^{n+1+r}}{{(n+1+r)!}} \left(\frac{w^r \sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{r}{k} (-1)^{r-k} f^{n+1} (a+kh)}{(x-a)^r}\right)\right)$$

$$=(x-a)^{n+1}\lim_{w \rightarrow \infty}\left( \sum_{r=0}^{w - 1} \frac{1}{{(n+1+r)!}} \left(w^r \sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{r}{k} (-1)^{r-k} f^{n+1} (a+kh)\right)\right)$$

This is also an expansion with terms of the form $c_k f^{n+1}(a+kh)$. For a particular value of $k$, $r$ will vary from $k$ to $w-1$ and also $k$ will vary from $0$ to $w-1$ in the entire expansion. So, $c_k=(x-a)^{n+1} \sum_{r=k}^{w-1} \binom{r}{k} \frac{ (-1)^{r-k} w^r }{(n+1+r)!}$

For LHS to be equal to RHS, the coefficients of $f^{n+1}(a+kh)$ terms must be equal on both sides. So,

$$\lim_{w\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{n!}\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \frac{k^r}{w^{r+1}}=(x-a)^{n+1} \lim_{w\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{r=k}^{w-1} \binom{r}{k} \frac{ (-1)^{r-k} w^r }{(n+1+r)!}$$

which implies

$$\lim_{w\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \frac{k^r}{w^{r+1}}=\lim_{w\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{r=k}^{w-1} \binom{r}{k} \frac{ (-1)^{r-k} w^r }{(n+1+r)!}$$

But this equation doesn't seem correct to me because LHS seems to be $0$ while RHS seems to diverge to infinity. Is this equation really correct or are there wrong steps in the proof?

Comment: This is similar to your previous question, but with an expression for remainder. But you should also specify the conditions on $f$ for which you want your starting identity to be valid. One of the reasonable conditions is that $f^{n+1}$ should be integrable otherwise the integral does not make sense. But do you have any more conditions on $f$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Whatever the conditions are usually. I guess $f$ is continuous, differentiable infinite times, well-behaved, etc. I read about this remainder formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) and tried to prove it by a similar method as that in my previous question. I think the conditions on $f$ are same as that on the remainder formula.

Comment: Conditions in your link do not include infinite times differentiability. And more importantly the Taylor theorem with remainder is a finite formula. It does not involve an infinite series (like your LHS).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Maybe you're looking at other forms of the remainder. I'm talking about the integral form which is also mentioned in the link. The integral form remainder is a definite integral and I've just expressed that integral as an infinite Riemann sum.

Comment: The integral remainder formula is also a finite one. It does not involve any infinite series.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm not sure what you mean. Every integral can be expressed as an infinite sum.

Comment: I am saying that Taylor theorem with any form of remainder is a finite formula. You are trying to prove a formula which has an infinite series. Thus the thing you are trying to prove is not really Taylor theorem with a remainder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72269/discussion-between-ryder-rude-and-paramanand-singh).